# Syntax error python 2.7

Tags: python, syntax, flask, pydub

Im have syntax error in def reverse app.route i know there is something wrong with getAudio but i dont know what.
Here is example from pydub documentation

```
    sound1 = AudioSegment.from_file("/path/to/sound.wav", 

format="wav")
```

And heres part of my code, commented

```
    @app.route('/Path/<filename>')  
def getFilePath(filename):
    return os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'files', filename)

@app.route('/Audio/<filename>')
def getAudio(filename):
    return AudioSegment.from_file(getFilePath(filename, format="wav")


@app.route('/rev/<filename>')
def reverse(filename):
    song = getAudio(filename)
    song = song.reverse()
```

Comment: Why is `getFilePath` even a route? Do you mean to expose your internal server file structure?

Comment: I did it just for tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return AudioSegment.from_file(getFilePath(filename, format="wav")
```

Looks like you're missing a parenthesis.

```
return AudioSegment.from_file(getFilePath(filename), format="wav")
```

Comment: Wow i was checking like 3 times, im sorry for wasting your time and thank you a lot. im gonna accept this as answer as soon possible.